# How final variable works if passed in a method?

Tags: java, methods, final

I have a very simple question and just asking to know more about `final` method arguments.

`final` variables can be initialized just once in its life. In JAVA method arguments are accepted as *pass by value* and reference is also passed as a value.

Now my question is :

#### How method doesn't know that passed object is `final` and already initialized?

Here is sample code:

```
public static void xyz(Abc obj) {
    System.out.println("hash code in xyz method :"+obj.hashCode());
    obj = new Abc(); // here there is no issue to initialize it again
}

public static void abc() {
    final Abc obj = new Abc();
    //obj=new Abc(); // final variable can be initialized just once

    System.out.println("hash code in abc method :"+obj.hashCode());
    xyz(obj);
}

public static void main(String[] a) {
    abc();
}
```

Comment: An object isn't final, a variable is.

Comment: Yes I have already modified the question title.

Comment: That's not what I mean. A reference or an object aren't final. Variables are final. When you use a variable as an argument the value of the reference it holds is passed.

Comment: But why this is not allowed in same `abc()` method? both are giving me same hash code.

Comment: Yah because both are referencing the same object.

Comment: @Braj, Same hash code does not necessarily imply same reference. It depends on how `class Abc` implemented `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `obj` variable in `abc` is not the same as the `obj` parameter in `xyz`.  When you call `xyz`, `xyz` works with a **copy** of the reference (NOTE: this is *not* a copy of the object, but it's a copy of the reference).  So when `obj = new Abc()` is executed in `xyz`, it modifies only the copy in `xyz`.  It has no effect on the `obj` in `abc()`, because the reference is passed by value.

Comment: Look at the hash code. I think its pointing to same object/reference.

Comment: @Braj Yes, it's like having two variables refer to the same object.  That's not relevant.  The point is, the variable (parameter) in `xyz` can be modified to refer to a different object, and the variable in `abc` cannot.

Comment: @Braj He's saying that the re-assignment applies to a copy of the passed in reference, not to the `final` reference. So even after re-assignment in the method, the `final` variable remains untouched.

Answer (score 3):

That's because references are passed by value; you cannot reseat references in Java. If you reassign `obj` to something else, it only has been reassigned within the scope of the method and not within the calling-scope. So what you have is only a **copy** of the reference of the final variable.

Hence the "finality" of the original object isn't violated.

If you want to make the parameter final as well, you can simply do:

```
public String myMethod(final Object myParameter) {
   ...
}
```

I think you might be confusing `final` variables with *immutability*. Immutability is something entirely different. It means that the underlying object's state cannot be modified once initialized. The *variable* that refers to this object may or may not be `final`; it has nothing to do with the mutability or immutability of an object. Indeed, the object that a `final` variable points to can be modified (if it is mutable) and using `final` will not guard against that. What it *does* guard against is the possibility of reassignment.

Comment: Its just for my learning and I know that if final is declared in method arguments then I can't reinitialize it. Thanks a lot for your kind and more informative response.

Comment: @Braj No worries. There's nothing wrong with asking questions and your question is very valid. It can be a source of confusion when you are just starting out.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing time

```
    Object          Reference    
 [some object]  <---  1234
```

And your variable

```
       initialized with value
obj    ---------------------->    1234
```

It can no longer be changed because it is `final`.

When you use it as an argument

```
xyz(obj);
...
public static void xyz(Abc someRandomNameNotToBeConfused) {
```

Java takes the value of `obj`, the reference `1234` and binds it to `someRandomNameNotToBeConfused`.

Now

```
                                initialized with value
someRandomNameNotToBeConfused   ---------------------->    1234
```

But `someRandomNameNotToBeConfused` can be changed because it is not `final`. So if you had a second `Abc` object

```
    Object          Reference    
 [some object]  <---  1234
 [other object] <---  678
```

You could change the reference that `someRandomNameNotToBeConfused` holds

```
someRandomNameNotToBeConfused = new Abc(); // 678
```

becomes

```
                                reassigned to
someRandomNameNotToBeConfused ------------------> 678
```

The variable `obj`  in the calling method remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

The reference is final, but the object it points at is not. When the reference is passed into `xyz`, it is copied, so the original reference is not modified.

There is no reason why the copy of a final reference is also final.
The reference in `abc()` was final, but the reference in `xyz()` is not.

If you are coming from a language like `C++`, this might look like a `const` violation where a `const` reference is passed into a function that has a non-`const` parameter, but Java's `final` does not work that way.

Note that the `hashCode()` can be overwritten by the object's class definition, so it may be equal even if a new object is created.

Comment: But why this is not allowed in same `abc()` method? both are giving me same hash code.