# How is my final array being modified?

Tags: java, class, variables, static, final

I have something similar to this:

```
(SomeClass)
public static final float[][][] values = {...};

public float[][][] variable = values;
```

So, I create a new instance of this class and pass the `values` to a `public` member of this class, like I did up there.

Thing is, when I work with `variable` now and change it and stuff, it gets changed for all instances of `SomeClass`.

`final` cant be modified after declaration I thought?
So why isn't `variable` more like a copy of `values` but gets modified like a `static` but **not** `final` variable?

Comment: `final` means you can't reassign the variable. It doesn't mean the object the variable refers to is immutable. Also, assignment doesn't create copies of objects.

Comment: It might help you [How final variable works if passed in a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949718/how-final-variable-works-if-passed-in-a-method)

Comment: @user2357112, Alright. Braj, Thanks, going to read this. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that when you do

```
public static final float[][][] values = {...};

public float[][][] variable = values;
```

both `values` and `variable` "point" to the same reference (i.e. to the same location in memory).

What `final` means is that you *cannot* change that reference (i.e. you can't make the variable refer to another location in memory). You can still modify the object the varible refers to.

Comment: thanks for that explanation. :) didn't know that finals work like that. so, `clone()` gives me just the same location in memory instead of a cloned thing somewhere else i guess?

Comment: @andy: You didn't call `clone` in the code you showed us. `clone` copies objects, but the default behavior is a shallow copy, not a deep copy; it won't clone the objects in an array of objects, and for multidimensional arrays, it won't clone the subarrays, only the top-level array.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, but i tried it before posting, without success, so i was just asking. alright, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because declaring `public float[][][] variable = values` is making a copy of the memory location of values. So changing `variable[][][]`, is changing the same memory location as `values[][][]`.

Use `Arrays.copyOf()`

`final float[][][] values`, simply means the `values` variable cannot be assigned to a new memory location.
I.e. `values = new float[][][]` would throw an exception.

Comment: alright. but wouldn't this get a bit bulky with `Arrays.copyOf()`? because i would have to do this for the arrays in the arrays and then put them together, as i see that?

Comment: `copyOf` won't cut it. It's a shallow copy, and this is a multidimensional array.

Comment: Ah good call, I've not used copyOf() on a multidimensional array.